# How do i make all inner divs fill the entire height of their parent div?

Tags: html, css

I would like to make all children divs fill the entire height of the parent div.
[image]
I would prefer to do that without a fixed height, just adjust to the height of the greatest child div **but** if the only option is to use JS I will set a fixed height.

I created the [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/exeLeCe/1/edit?html,css,output) to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the `display: table` property. You can simulate table-behaviour in css, including dynamic elements that all have the same height. BTW, yes it's the good way of using tables, not the bad way.

http://jsbin.com/exeLeCe/7/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Ria Elliger you can use a table-layout for this.

You should make a extra element for the table. This way you can align the table to the middle as shown on your picture:

```
  <div class="con">
    <div id="table">
      <div>gdsgsdg sg sdg sdf gdf gd fg dfg</div>
      <div>sdfkjsd kfjsdf sdfj sdfj sdlk fslkd fskldf  sdf sdf sd f</div>
      <div>gdsgsdg sg sdg sdf gdf gd fg dfg</div>
      <div>gdsgsdg sg sdg sdf gdf gd fg dfg</div>
      <div>gdsgsdg sg sdg sdf gdf gd fg dfg</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Where every div inside the table acts as a `table-cell`:

```
#table > div {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Because the `table-cell` will be aligned to the top as default, you want to change it so it expends to the top. That's why is use `vertical-align: bottom;`

Now you can align the table to the middle of your parent element:

```
#table
{
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  border-spacing: 5px 0;
}
```

I used  `border-spacing` so you can see the seperation for each cell. This is only assigned to the left and the right side of each cell.

### [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/exeLeCe/11/edit)

Comment: Tnx. I selected the other as answer just because she was first.

Answer (score 0):

use this css code for that html,,,,,,,

```
.con
 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  width:400px;
  height:160px;
}

.con div  {
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 50px;
  height:100%;
  position:float;
  overflow:hidden;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for inner DIV:

```
.con div {
display: table-cell;
border: 1px solid gray;
width: 50px;
}
```